# Meaningless result for ln(1 + x) function

Tags: c, function, if-statement, while-loop, integer

My task is:

> The value of **ln(1 + x)** can be calculated using the formula given below. Write a C function that takes a real number **x** and an integer **n** as its arguments and returns the value of **ln(1 + x)** where **n** determines the number of terms in the summation. Don't use the `pow` function.
>
> **ln(1+x) = x - x<sup>2</sup>/2 + x<sup>3</sup>/3 - x<sup>4</sup>/4 ...**

As you see at the below of the photo results are meaningless. What is the problem in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0, n = 1, k = 1;
    double total_x = 0.0;
    
    printf("Enter the x value for calculate ( ln(1+x) ) : ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter the n value for calculate ( ln(1+x) ) : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("Result can not be calculated\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (k <= n) {
        if ((k % 2) != 0) {
            total_x += x / k;
            x *= x;
            k++;
        } else {
            total_x -= x / k;
            x *= x;
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("Result of ln(1+x)=%.2lf\n", total_x);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to write the given function but the results are unexpected:

[image: DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY CODE]

Comment: You made all numbers ints so fraction parts get chopped off in every calculation

Comment: @Alperen Budak You need to use at least the floating arithmetic as for example total_x += x/( double )k

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as text.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the type of `x` should be `double` so the input, multiplications and divisions are performed using floating point arithmetics
- the result should be `0.0` for `n = 0`.
- `x *= x;` is incorrect: you are computing **x<sup>2<sup>i</sup></sup>** instead of **x<sup>i</sup>**. you should use a separate variable variable for the power.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    double x;
    
    printf("Enter the x value for calculate ( ln(1+x) ) : ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the n value for calculate ( ln(1+x) ) : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    double power = -1.0;
    double total_x = 0.0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        power *= -x;
        total_x += power / k;
    }
    printf("Result of ln(1+x)= %f\n", total_x);
    return 0;
}
```